# How to give a space between href?

Tags: html, html-lists

I wrote my  code here but it  won't give space

```
<a href="opinion.jsp"><font color="red"><h3>Recommendation</h3></font></a>
<a href="FindoneServ"><font color="red"><h3>Review Mining</h3></font></a>
<a href="rank.jsp"><font color="red"><h3>Generate Graph</h3></font></a>
<a href="index1.jsp"><font color="red"><h3>Sign out</h3></font></a>
```

i need a output like this

```
Recommendation          Review Mining           Generate Graph        Signout
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean "it won't give space"?

Comment: @DipeshParmar  need a white space between the href.

Comment: @AndyLester need a white space between the href

Comment: Please explain it again with more words and different words.  What is "the href"?  Are you talking about how the page looks in a browser?  What is a space?  Horizontal space or vertical?

Comment: @AndyLester i need a output like                              Recommendation        Review mining         Generate Graph     Signout

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in your code:

1. The `font` tag - Don't use this, it's ugly, deprecated and altogether useless. Style your elements with css.
2. A block-level element `h3` inside an inline element `a`<sup>*</sup>. This is invalid HTML and makes no sense semantically.

   - A `h3` is meant to be a headline, it does not logically fit into an anchor element.
   - `h3` produce linebreaks and thus all your links are put on a single line each.

Depending on what exactly you want to do, this markup is more suited:

```
<!-- Use an unordered list for your anchor elements-->
<ul class="mylinks">
     <li><a href="opinion.jsp">Recommendation</a><li>
     <li><a href="FindoneServ">Review Mining</a><li>
     <li><a href="rank.jsp"   >Generate Graph</a><li>
     <li><a href="index1.jsp" >Sign out</a><li>
</ul>
```

and the css accordingly

```
<!-- put this in the <head> of your html document --> 
<style type="text/css">
.mylinks li{
    float:left;   /* Fit all your links nicely in one line*/
    margin:0 5px; /* Give them to the left and right a little room to breathe */
    /* You can adjust the space by modifying the 5px value, */
    /* the 0 modifies the top/bottom spacing */
}

.mylinks a{
   color:red; /* fancy red color for your links*/
}
</style>
```

*: well at least in HTML4. The question still remains whether such a kind of tag nesting makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using heading tags, which by default have a line wrap after them.

To change this, you can set the `display` CSS property which will align the element in with other elements:

```
h3 { 
  display: inline; 
}
```

You might reconsider using the `<h3>` altogether.  It is appropriate as a heading for other content, not for navigation, in general.  I also recommend dropping the `<font>` tag.  You don't need it.  You can, and should, use CSS for styling.

Comment: It's not only "You don't need it". It's deprecated since a long time now. The usage is strongly discouraged and browser support might be dropped anytime (though I suspect this will never happen).

Comment: @Christoph It will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using: unordered listed inside a div.

```
<!--HTML-->
<div id="Navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="opinion.jsp">Recommendation</a></li>
<li><a href="FindoneServ">Review Mining</a></li>
<li><a href="rank.jsp">Generate Graph</a></li>
<li><a href="index1.jsp">Sign out</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<!--CSS-->

#Navigation
{
      color: #9000A1;
      font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

Comment: This would be a good answer... 20years ago. *Tables are for tabular data, not for layout!*

Comment: I guess this still does not fit the OPs needs, since he does not want to have linebreaks between the links. Nonetheless I will revoke my -1...